# Number of partitions of $50$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integer-partitions

Does someone know the number of partitions of the integer $50$? I mean, in how many ways can I write $50$ as a sum of positive integers? 
I know that there's a table by Euler, which is useful to know in how many ways you can write $50$ as a sum of $m$ different numbers, but this table stops at $m=11$, so I can't end the calculation and calculate in how many ways in which I can write $50$ as a sum of (any) different numbers. Thank you

Comment: Look up the stars and bars method. You could use it on every integer from $1$ to $50$ and sum them up to get total number of partitions.

Comment: Depends on whether you count differently ordered sums as different, like 20+20+10 versus 10+20+20. stars and bars assumes order matters, and also needs to know how many summands.

Comment: @anonymaker00010001:  What you describe may count *compositions* of an integer, but not the *partitions*.

Comment: Also, you can could use Eulers recurrence formula. It says that $p(n)=p(n-1)+p(n-2)+p(n-5)+p(n-7)\ldots$ where the numbers $1,2,5,7$ are the generalized pentagonal numbers $g_k=\frac{k(3k-1)}{2}$

Comment: More extensive tables are found online.  See for example the [OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A000041) for the partition function, and the table to $1000$ there linked by David Wilson.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [table at OEISWiki](http://oeis.org/wiki/Partition_function), the partition number of $50$ is $204226$.

Comment: I was really looking for this kind of table. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

It is known --- and it is a difficult and famous result proven by Hardy and Ramanujan --- that the number of partitions of $n$ is approximately (when $n$ is large) given by $p(n) \sim \frac{ e^{ \pi\sqrt{2n/3} } }{4n\sqrt{3} }$. With $n = 50$, this yelds $p(50) \sim 217590$.

Bad news : there is no useful closed form of $p(n)$. But you can also compute it with the well-known recurrence formula

$$p(n) = p(n-1) + p(n-2) - p(n-5) - p(n-7) + p(n-12) - ... $$

where $1,2,5,7,12$ are the  [(generalized) pentagonal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number).

For $n=50$ this could be done with the help of a computer.

(edit : well, as Theophile mentioned, there are tables up to $p(250)$ and more. Also, the sign mistake in the Euler recurrence has been corrected. Thanks !)

Comment: What does $p(50) \sim 198680$ mean? As far as I know asymptotical analysis if $c_1 \sim c_2$ for two constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ then $c_1 = c_2$, isn't it?

Comment: I believe your approximation is off. The formula should give $p(50) \sim 217590$, not $198680$.

Comment: It's just an approximate value.

Comment: @Théophile : yup, mistake in my computations. Thanks

Comment: Why, according to the table posted by @Théophile the exact result is 204226, while the result using Ramanujan-Hardy formula is 217590? I knew that that formula is exact approximating to the nearest integer number.

Comment: @xyzt Hardy-Ramanujan is not approximating to the nearest integer.

Comment: @xyzt maybe you're referring to the series found by Rademacher?

Comment: Probably I misunderstood.

Comment: Your reccurance formula doesn't seem like it can possiblly be right. It seems to imply that p(n) is less than p(n-1) which is clearly absurd.

Comment: @PeterGreen It should be $p(n) = p(n-1)+p(n-2)-p(n-5)-p(n-7)+\ldots$, with the signs cycling through $(+,+,-,-)$.

Comment: [The source mentioned](https://oeis.org/A000041/b000041.txt) gives them up to $p(10000)$.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 wow, 10,000 is really small I can do it up to 100,000 no sweat by using the java biginteger class

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo More terms may be easily computable, but 10000 is a standard length for an OEIS b-file.

Answer (score 5):

You can solve this problem using [Euler's recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Recurrence_formula).

It tells you that $p_n=\sum\limits_{i\neq 0}^{}(-1)^{i-1} p_{n-i(3i-1)/2}$.

Of course the function $f(x)=x(3x-1)/2$ is positive everywhere except $(0,1/3)$ so this is a good recursion. Also note that $p_n$ is defined to be $0$ for negative values.

We can use this recursion to calculate $p_n$ from the previous values in time $\mathcal O(\sqrt n)$ , so we can certainly obtain $P_n$ from scratch in time $\mathcal O(\sqrt n n)$

```
Here is some c++ code:


#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long lli;

const int MAX=100;
lli P[MAX];

int main(){
    P[0]=1;
    for(int a=1;a<MAX;a++){
        for(int b=-2*sqrt(a); b<= 2*sqrt(a); b++){// do recursion with all possible pentagonal numbers
            if( (b*(3*b-1) )/2 > a || b==0  ) continue;
            if(b%2) P[a]+= P[a- (b*(3*b-1) )/2];
            else P[a]-= P[a- (b*(3*b-1) )/2];
        }
    }
    printf("%lld\n",P[50]);
}
```

The output is $204226$

Comment: Interesting way!! :)

Comment: Any reason for calculating up to P(100) when the goal is to find p(50)?

Comment: @PeterGreen nope no reason, just wanted to show off

Comment: The largest value fitting in a signed 32-bit integer would be `p(121)`